# How to graph kinetic plots?

Tags: physics

https://i.stack.imgur.com/usNWM.png

I don't understand how to solve. F1 and 2 are both equal, rihgt? What is the question asking?

Answer (score 0):

No, they depict three different situations each one with its own answer. The first one supposes $F_1=F_2$, the total force is null, so the velocity doesn't change and neither the kinetic energy. The plot is the second one. For the third, $F_1<F_2$, the total force increases still more the velocity and, consequently the kinetic energy. The best plot is the first.